# How would I call a function from a class || trait with a variable and pass arguments?

Tags: class, oop, arguments, traits

that's how my class structure looks like (lib.php):

```
trait smartMethods{    

     function Numbers($length,$position){

           echo $length.$position."\n";

           }

       }


class smartBrute  {


Private $config,$smlist;
use smartMethods;


function init(){

foreach($this->config as $k => $v){

    $inp = "";
    foreach($v as $k2 => $v2){
    ($inp == "" ? $inp = $v2 : $inp .= ",".$v2); 
    }



         $this->{$k}($inp); // Here Is Problem

    }


} //EO init

} //EO Class
```

call class (init.php) :

```
$options["Numbers"] = Array(2,1); 
$brute = new smartBrute($options);
```

$this->{$k}($inp); <- Here is my problem function Numbers require 2 argument. without argument like this $this->{$k}() it works but i can't understand how to pass in this situation arguments.

Answer (score 0):

i find this kind of solution,

```
function init(){

     foreach($this->config as $k => $v){


     call_user_func_array(array($this,$k),$v); // call trait Method funcs


}


}
```

i passed arguments with [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) this function